# How to serve JSP files using Jetty?

Tags: jsp, jetty

I'm embedding jetty, serving a single servlet and some static content.  I've downloaded jetty from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.4.5.v20110725/dist/, and added all jars from JETTY_HOME/lib/* and JETTY_HOME/lib/jsp/* to user librarys in eclipe; these user librarys have been added to my project.  If I put a JSP file in my my static content folder (./webapps/static/) and view it at http://localhost:8080/static/test.jsp, the java expression are not evaluated and I get shown the full contents of the file.

What am I missing?

My main java class:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);               

        // Create a resource handler for static content.
        ResourceHandler staticResourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        staticResourceHandler.setResourceBase("./webapps/static/");
        staticResourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);        
        //staticResourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html",  });         
        //staticResourceHandler.setCacheControl("no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate");

        // Create context handler for static resource handler.
        ContextHandler staticContextHandler = new ContextHandler();
        staticContextHandler.setContextPath("/static");       
        staticContextHandler.setHandler(staticResourceHandler);        

        // Create servlet context handler for main servlet.
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");       
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/");

        // Create a handler list to store our static and servlet context handlers.
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { staticContextHandler, servletContextHandler });

        // Add the handlers to the server and start jetty.
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }           

}
```

My JSP file I want to serve:

```
<html>
<body>
Time: <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</body>
</html>
```

List of jars in JETTY_HOME/lib/:

```
$ ls -1 ./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/*.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-ajp-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-annotations-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-client-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-continuation-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-deploy-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-http-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-io-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-jmx-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-jndi-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-overlay-deployer-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-plus-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-policy-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-rewrite-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-security-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-server-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-servlet-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-servlets-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-util-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-webapp-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-websocket-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jetty-xml-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar
```

List of jars in JETTY_HOME/lib/jsp/:

```
$ ls -1 ./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/*.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/com.sun.el_1.0.0.v201004190952.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/ecj-3.6.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/javax.el_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp_2.1.0.v201004190952.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-2.1-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.1.0.v201007080150.jar
./jetty-distribution-7.4.5.v20110725/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish_1.2.0.v201004190952.jar
```

---

Update: The suggestion from @JJ helped work out how to correctly serve JSP file with jetty.  My only issue now is how to stop jetty from listing the directory contents of ./webapps/jsp/.  The most basic fix I have for the moment is to put index.html or index.jsp in ./webapps/jsp/, but I would prefer be able to configure jetty to return a forbidden error.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // Create a resource handler for static content.
        ResourceHandler staticResourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        staticResourceHandler.setResourceBase("./webapps/static/");
        staticResourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);

        // Create context handler for static resource handler.
        ContextHandler staticContextHandler = new ContextHandler();
        staticContextHandler.setContextPath("/static");
        staticContextHandler.setHandler(staticResourceHandler);

        // Create WebAppContext for JSP files.
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/jsp");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("./webapps/jsp/");
        // ??? THIS DOES NOT STOP DIR LISTING OF ./webapps/jsp/ ???
        webAppContext.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");   

        // Create servlet context handler for main servlet.
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()), "/*");

        // Create a handler list to store our static, jsp and servlet context handlers.
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { staticContextHandler, webAppContext, servletContextHandler });

        // Add the handlers to the server and start jetty.
        server.setHandler(handlers);    
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing some key piece which tells Jetty to parse the served files as JSP content instead of simply a static file. I can't see exactly what you're missing without being able to debug your code however I recommend you check this reference about embedding Jetty:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty

In particular I think this piece of code may be relevant to your issue:

```
// assumes that this directory contains .html and .jsp files
// This is just a directory within your source tree, and can be exported as part of your normal .jar
final String WEBAPPDIR = "com/xxx/yyy/webapp";
final Server server = new Server(httpServerPort);
final String CONTEXTPATH = "/admin";

// for localhost:port/admin/index.html and whatever else is in the webapp directory
final URL warUrl = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPPDIR);
final String warUrlString = warUrl.toExternalForm();
server.setHandler(new WebAppContext(warUrlString, CONTEXTPATH));
```