# Embedded Jetty. JSP not configured

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

I write in Eclipse an application that connect my file Calculator.war.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(1490);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar("D:/Calculator.war");
        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!console.nextLine().equals("stop"));
        console.close();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

If i open in a browser link localhost:1490 i receive an error message: "JSP not configured and smth about /lib/jsp"
If i write localhost:1490/ServletCalculator everything is OK.

I connected to JARs to the project jetty-all-8.1.7.v20120910.jar и servlet-api-3.0.jar.
Then i tried to connect jars from /lib/jsp but it didn't succeed.
I DON'T USE MAVEN
Is it possible to solve this problem? How?

Comment: What's the content of your web.xml?

Comment: You might find this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160220/how-to-serve-jsp-files-using-jetty

Answer (score 1):

Enabling JSP support in Jetty is a complex job. Multiple
steps must be performed. Finally, I have succeeded and I 
have documented the entire process in this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/java/jetty/embedded/)
under *Enabling JavaServer Pages* header.

Answer (score 0):

here is my web.xml. But inspite of the fact that there is no information about index.jsp it loads by with adress localhost:1490/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletCalculator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>main_pack.ServletCalculator</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletCalculator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletCalculator</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```